# Create branch after checkin - TFS 2010

Tags: tfs

I have checked out from the main trunk and made some changes that I do not want to go back into the main trunk. If I create a branch in TFS *after* I have already checked out the code, how do I check my code into the new branch that did not exist when I originally checked out the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to [shelve your changes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w6y8ezzs.aspx) and then [unshelve it into another branch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s6bx4df3.aspx)